# Can we have vSphere Advance and Enterprise editions in same farm?

Tags: central-processing-unit, vmware-vsphere

One customer has recnetly bought the existing :

1 Physical server with 2 CPUs, for which he bought vSphere Advance licenses, 1 per CPU
1 Physical server with 2 CPUs, for which he bought vSphere Enterprice licenses, 1 per CPU

1 Physical server with 2 CPUs, for which he bought vSphere VCenter license.

It seems they are facing some problems, and from what they told me, they cannot have in same farm, Advance and Etnerprise Edition.
Is it correct ? Can or we cannot have both in same farm ?

Is it possible to downgrade The Enterprise Edition to Advance ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Yes you can, it's no problem at all.

And as for downgrade, the licence really only gives you additional features, just ignore them if you wish.

Comment: Exactly - you can have whatever mix of ESX licenses that you want in ESX hosts managed by a vCenter server however the functionality of your infrastructure will depend on the specific spread of licenses - you can only be guaranteed that the functionality of the most restrictive license will be available on all ESX hosts. With the above mix you could have all hosts in a HA cluster with vMotion enabled but wouldn't be able to enable DRS or use Storage vMotion (for example).